# Quiero hacer un test de velocidad lectora en consola (C#)

Tags: c#, array, archivo, consola

Estoy haciendo un programa/juego en C# que es básicamente un test de velocidad lectora de 6 niveles y quiero que se muestre en consola algo parecido a esto:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fXh9KaavY6c

El problema es que no muestra ni siquiera una sola palabra del contenido del archivo de texto.

¿Podrían decirme si hay algún error en el código?

---

```
Console.WindowHeight = 40;
        Console.WindowWidth = 150;
        Console.SetCursorPosition(75, 20);
        Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Green;
        int opcion = 0;
            Console.WriteLine("Bienvenido a este ejercicio de velocidad lectora");
            Console.WriteLine("Selecciona el nivel de dificultad (velocidad) deseado");
            Console.WriteLine("Opción 1: Nivel más bajo");
            Console.WriteLine("Opción 2: Nivel bajo");
            Console.WriteLine("Opción 3: Nivel medio-bajo");
            Console.WriteLine("Opción 4: Nivel medio-alto");
            Console.WriteLine("Opción 5: Nivel alto");
            Console.WriteLine("Opción 6: Nivel más alto");
            opcion = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            switch (opcion)
            {
                case 1:
                    {
                    Console.WriteLine("Bienvenido al nivel 1");
                    Console.WriteLine("Presiona 1 para continuar");
                    Console.ReadLine();
                    int continuar = 0;
                    switch(continuar)
                    {
                        case 1:
                            {
                                StreamReader lectura = File.OpenText(@"C:\Users\wuise\Desktop\DfC\Archivos de Texto\Nivel 1.txt");
                                string contenido = lectura.ReadToEnd();
                                string[] palabras = contenido.Split(' ', ',', '.', ';');
                                lectura.Close();
                                for (int x = 0; x < palabras.Length; x++)
                                {
                                    Console.WriteLine(palabras[x]);
                                    Thread.Sleep(600);
                                    Console.Clear();
                                }
                                break;
                            }
                    }
                    break;
                    }
                case 2:
                    {
                    Console.WriteLine("Bienvenido al nivel 2");
                    Console.WriteLine("Presiona 1 para continuar");
                    Console.ReadLine();
                    int continuar = 0;
                    switch (continuar)
                    {
                        case 1:
                            {
                                StreamReader lectura = File.OpenText(@"C:\Users\wuise\Desktop\DfC\Archivos de Texto\Nivel 2.txt");
                                string contenido = lectura.ReadToEnd();
                                string[] palabras = contenido.Split(' ', ',', '.', ';');
                                lectura.Close();
                                for (int x = 0; x < palabras.Length; x++)
                                {
                                    Console.WriteLine(palabras[x]);
                                    Console.ReadKey(true);
                                    Thread.Sleep(300);
                                    Console.Clear();
                                }
                                break;
                            }
                    }
                    break;
                    }
                case 3:
                    {
                    Console.WriteLine("Bienvenido al nivel 3");
                    Console.WriteLine("Presiona 1 para continuar");
                    Console.ReadLine();
                    int continuar = 0;
                    switch (continuar)
                    {
                        case 1:
                            {
                                StreamReader lectura = File.OpenText(@"C:\Users\wuise\Desktop\DfC\Archivos de Texto\Nivel 3.txt");
                                string contenido = lectura.ReadToEnd();
                                string[] palabras = contenido.Split(' ', ',', '.', ';');
                                lectura.Close();
                                for (int x = 0; x < palabras.Length; x++)
                                {
                                    Console.WriteLine(palabras[x]);
                                    Console.ReadKey(true);
                                    Thread.Sleep(200);
                                    Console.Clear();
                                }
                                break;
                            }
                    }
                    break;
                    }
                case 4:
                    {
                    Console.WriteLine("Bienvenido al nivel 4");
                    Console.WriteLine("Presiona 1 para continuar");
                    Console.ReadLine();
                    int continuar = 0;
                    switch (continuar)
                    {
                        case 1:
                            {
                                StreamReader lectura = File.OpenText(@"C:\Users\wuise\Desktop\DfC\Archivos de Texto\Nivel 4.txt");
                                string contenido = lectura.ReadToEnd();
                                string[] palabras = contenido.Split(' ', ',', '.', ';');
                                lectura.Close();
                                for (int x = 0; x < palabras.Length; x++)
                                {
                                    Console.WriteLine(palabras[x]);
                                    Console.ReadKey(true);
                                    Thread.Sleep(150);
                                    Console.Clear();
                                }
                                break;
                            }
                    }
                    break;
                    }
                case 5:
                    {
                    Console.WriteLine("Bienvenido al nivel 5");
                    Console.WriteLine("Presiona 1 para continuar");
                    Console.ReadLine();
                    int continuar = 0;
                    switch (continuar)
                    {
                        case 1:
                            {
                                StreamReader lectura = File.OpenText(@"C:\Users\wuise\Desktop\DfC\Archivos de Texto\Nivel 5.txt");
                                string contenido = lectura.ReadToEnd();
                                string[] palabras = contenido.Split(' ', ',', '.', ';');
                                lectura.Close();
                                for (int x = 0; x < palabras.Length; x++)
                                {
                                    Console.WriteLine(palabras[x]);
                                    Console.ReadKey(true);
                                    Thread.Sleep(120);
                                    Console.Clear();
                                }
                                break;
                            }
                    }
                    break;
                    }
                case 6:
                    {
                    Console.WriteLine("Bienvenido al nivel 6");
                    Console.WriteLine("Presiona 1 para continuar");
                    Console.ReadLine();
                    int continuar = 0;
                    switch (continuar)
                    {
                        case 1:
                            {
                                StreamReader lectura = File.OpenText(@"C:\Users\wuise\Desktop\DfC\Archivos de Texto\Nivel 6.txt");
                                string contenido = lectura.ReadToEnd();
                                lectura.Close();
                                string[] palabras = contenido.Split(' ', ',', '.', ';');
                                for (int x = 0; x < palabras.Length; x++)
                                {
                                    Console.WriteLine(palabras[x]);
                                    Console.ReadKey(true);
                                    Thread.Sleep(100);
                                    Console.Clear();
                                }
                                break;
                            }
                    }
                    break;
                    }
                default:
                    {
                    Console.WriteLine("La opción que usted marcó no existe");
                    break;
                    }
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/aP2F2.png

Comment: porque repites tantas veces el codigo? la lectura del archivo es siempre igual solo cambia la ruta, podrias llevar eso a un metodo separado

Comment: ¿Cómo se puede hacer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema lo tienes en las lineas

```
int continuar = 0;
switch (continuar) 
{
   case 1:
   {
```

te das cuenta lo que sucede, no? justa ante de evaluar el `switch` pone el valor de la variable `continuar` en cero, y solo evaluas el 1, en resumen NUNCA va a ingresar

Podrias hacerlo mucho mas simple con algo como esto

```
Console.WriteLine("Bienvenido a este ejercicio de velocidad lectora");
Console.WriteLine("Selecciona el nivel de dificultad (velocidad) deseado");
Console.WriteLine("Opción 1: Nivel más bajo");
Console.WriteLine("Opción 2: Nivel bajo");
Console.WriteLine("Opción 3: Nivel medio-bajo");
Console.WriteLine("Opción 4: Nivel medio-alto");
Console.WriteLine("Opción 5: Nivel alto");
Console.WriteLine("Opción 6: Nivel más alto");
int opcion = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());


string fileName = "";
int nivel;

switch (opcion)
{
    case 1:
        nivel = 1;
        fileName = "Nivel 1.txt";
        break;
    case 2:
        nivel = 2;
        fileName = "Nivel 2.txt";
        break;
    case 3:
        nivel = 3;
        fileName = "Nivel 3.txt";
        break;

    //aqui define el resto

    default:
        Console.WriteLine("La opción que usted marcó no existe");
        nivel = 0;
        break;

}

if(nivel == 0)
{
    return;
}

Console.WriteLine("Bienvenido al nivel {0}", nivel);
Console.WriteLine("Presiona alguna key para continuar");
Console.ReadLine();

string path = @"C:\Users\wuise\Desktop\DfC\Archivos de Texto";
string fullPath = Path.Combine(path, fileName);

string contenido = File.ReadAllText(fullPath);
string[] palabras = contenido.Split(' ', ',', '.', ';');

for (int x = 0; x < palabras.Length; x++)
{
    Console.WriteLine(palabras[x]);
    Thread.Sleep(600);
    Console.Clear();
}
```

Como observaras se repite muuuuucho menos el codigo

Comment: Gracias, la verdad es que apenas estoy empezando y no sabía que se podía hacer eso